# Can JSP EL do direct attribute access

Tags: jsp, el

This really surprised me ! I have the following code in my JSP.

```
<c:param name="title" value="${slideShow.title}" />
```

This code was working till I refactored the SlideShow class and made all attributes public and removed getters/setters. So it seems to me that EL works only with getter and not direct attribute access. Is this true ? Is there any way to get it to work with direct attributes instead of going through getters ?

Comment: Have you considered using some MVC framework, like Spring MVC?

Comment: @BorisTreukhov I am using old and painful technology - Struts 1.3 + EJB 3.0 . This is a small but production quality project which will be used for some Struts + EJB + JUnit training. I read that a good practice for EJB 3.x Entities is to make the attributes public and use direct attribute access. However, the moment I did that, the JSP's started failing. I am thinking of adding another layer of DTO's with getters/setters for the view layer. However, the fact that EL did not work without getters puzzled me.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov Cannot change the technology stack, since it will be used as a reference for a specific training.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question I first thought it's about setting values :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSP EL relies strictly on Java Bean specification, so it cannot use other conventions to access property values.

Actually, you can read about this is [StackOverflow EL tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

So it's possible to invoke non-getter methods(not attributes) but only from certain EL vesion:

> Since EL 2.2, which is maintained as part of Servlet 3.0 / JSP 2.2 (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6, etc), it's possible to invoke non-getter methods, if necessary with arguments.
>
> E.g. ${bean.find(param.id)} with

```
public Something find(String id) {
    return someService.find(id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. I guess I am going to create a layer of DTO's with getter/setters