# How to access an object via a method `get()` in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, guava

I have an container object that contains a google/Guava `Optional` and I want to access the content of this `Optinal` in jsp.

```
import com.google.common.base.Optional;
public class Container {       
   private Optional<User> user;
   public Optional<User> getUser(){return this.user;}
}

public class User{
   private String name;
   public String getName() {return this.name;}
}
```

*A `Optional` has a method `get()` to obtain the inner object. http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#get%28%29*

I have already tried (`${container}` ins an instance of `Container`):

```
<c:out value="${container.user.name}" />
<c:out value="${container.user.get.name}" />
<c:out value="${container.user..name}" />
```

none of them work (Tomcat 7.42). Does anybody has an idea how to solve this, **without** adding a new property to the container (`getUser2(){return this.user.get();}`)?

Comment: `${container.user}` will return `Optional<User>`, so after that you will have to use the proper getter from `Optional` to retrieve the data from `User`.

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121166/can-jsp-el-do-direct-attribute-access

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza: the problem is that the "propper" getter form `Optinal` has the name `get`!

Comment: Then use `${container.user.get().name}`, but you should verify that the EL library in your Tomcat installation supports this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Sotirios Delimanolis

since Servlet 3.0 / JSP 2.2 one can use

```
 <c:out value="${container.user.get().name}" />
```