# Java 8 Optionals and JSP

Tags: java, jsp, option-type, spring-form

Does anybody have an idea how to use Optional objects on JSP?

I have a class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project {

@Expose
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
private Customer endCustomer;
....

public Optional<Customer> getEndCustomer() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(endCustomer);
}

public void setEndCustomer(Customer endCustomer) {
    this.endCustomer = endCustomer;
}
....
}
```

And i have jsp:

```html
<td>
   <form:select class="form-control" id="endCustomer" path="endCustomer.id" tabindex="4">
       <form:options items="${endCustomers}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
   </form:select>
</td>
```

this part doesn't work for obvious reasons: `path="endCustomer.id"`

is there a workaround?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you specify more ? have you tried `endCustomer.get().id`?

Comment: @soorapadman tried, didn't work.

Comment: Watch this issue on JakartaEE/EL : [ELResolver for java.util.Optional](https://github.com/jakartaee/expression-language/issues/176)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
<td>
   <form:select class="form-control" id="endCustomer" path="${endCustomer.get().id}" tabindex="4">
       <form:options items="${endCustomers}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
   </form:select>
</td>
```

Related question [How to access an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937487/how-to-access-an-object-via-a-method-get-in-jsp)

Comment: @VladyslavNikolaiev привет, к сожалению это не работает для path, так только значение можно вывести.

Comment: @UnknwnArtist, try this
`path="<c:out value=\"${endCustomer.get().id\"}/>"`
or even
`<c:out value="path= ${endCustomer.get().id}"/> `
I'm not sure in those statements correctness

Comment: You cannot call arbitrary methods in EL, so get() doesn't work. PS endCustomer.id is resolved to endCustomer.getId().