# Property [id] not found on type [java.util.Optional]

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to perform crud operation with spring boot and i am new to it. I have successfully performed delete and create part. The problem i am having when i am trying to edit my fields. I am using MYSQL as my database. I am having error mentioned in question title. Any help to resolve it and please check my logic i think my logic is wrong in /showUpdate method. When i press edit button then it is not taking me to edit page and throwing me this error.

> My controller class is pasted below:

[Snapshot of Actual error i am having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgDPj.png)

```
    package com.bilal.location.controllers;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Optional;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import com.bilal.location.entities.Location;
    import com.bilal.location.service.LocationService;
    @Controller
    public class LocationController {

    @Autowired
    LocationService service;

    @RequestMapping("/showCreate")
    public String showCreate() {
        return "createLocation";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/savLoc")
    public String saveLocation(@ModelAttribute("location") Location location,ModelMap modelMap) {

        Location locationSaved = service.saveLocation(location);
        String msg = "Location saved with id: " + locationSaved.getId();
        modelMap.addAttribute("msg", msg);
        return "createLocation";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/displayLocations")
    public String displayLocations(ModelMap modelMap) {

        List<Location> locations = service.getAllLocations(); 
        modelMap.addAttribute("locations", locations);
        return "displayLocations";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/deleteLocation")
    public String deleteLocation(@RequestParam("id")int id,ModelMap modelMap) {

        Location location = new Location();
        location.setId(id);
        service.deleteLocation(location);
        List<Location> locations = service.getAllLocations();
        modelMap.addAttribute("locations", locations);
        return "displayLocations";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/showUpdate")
    public String showUpdate(@RequestParam("id")int id,ModelMap modelMap) {

        Optional<Location> location = service.getLocationById(id);
        modelMap.addAttribute("location", location);
        return "updateLocation";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/updateLoc")
    public String updateLocation(@ModelAttribute("location") Location location,ModelMap modelMap) {
        service.updateLocation(location);
        List<Location> locations = service.getAllLocations();
        modelMap.addAttribute("locations", locations);
        return "displayLocations";
    }
}
```

Display Location JSP Page:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@page isELIgnored="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Display Locations</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Locations:</h2>
<%--Table Starting from here --%>
<table>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>code</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>type</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items = "${locations}" var="location" >
<tr>
<td>${location.id}</td>
<td>${location.code}</td>
<td>${location.name}</td>
<td>${location.type}</td>
<td><a href= "deleteLocation?id=${location.id}">delete</a></td>
<td><a href= "showUpdate?id=${location.id}">edit</a></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
<%--Table Ending here --%>
<a href="showCreate">Add Location</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Update Location JSP Page

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@page isELIgnored="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Create Location</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="updateLoc" method="post">
<pre>
 id:   <input type="text" name="id" value = "${location.id}" readonly/>
 code: <input type="text" name="code" value = "${location.code}"/>
 name: <input type="text" name="name" value = "${location.name}"/>
 type: rural <input type ="radio" name="type" value ="RURAL" ${location.type=='URBAN'?'checked':'' }/>
    Urban <input type ="radio" name="type" value= "URBAN" ${location.type=='RURAL'?'checked':'' }/>
 <input type="submit" name="save"/>
</pre>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937487/how-to-access-an-object-via-a-method-get-in-jsp

Comment: Still dont understand could you please eleborate. The thing i understand that i needed getters and setters to get id am i right.

Comment: Somebody help me to understand what is the cause of the error and how to resolve it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the error message carefully. It says you are trying to acces `.id`, but not on your Location, but on an `Optional` instead - which doesn't have that property.

Check your code:

```
@RequestMapping("/showUpdate")
public String showUpdate(@RequestParam("id")int id,ModelMap modelMap) {

    Optional<Location> location = service.getLocationById(id);
    modelMap.addAttribute("location", location);
    return "updateLocation";
}
```

You are not adding the location, but an Optional that might contain the location.
You can check whether an Optional holds a value by calling `ìsPresent()`, e.g.

```
if (location.isPresent()) {
    modelMap.addAttribute("location", location.get());
} else {
    // ERROR?
}
```

More on Optional, if you are not familiar: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Comment: Actually i wanted to use location not optional but it is not supported now. For example full function will look like this: Location location = service.getLocationById(id); But then i get error on get location by id method. I am force to use optional here and i dont know its usage.

Comment: I mean, when used judiciously, Optional is a great tool. Especially for a method which may or may not return a result, like searching a location by ID. The alternatives are returning NULL, which is rather implicit and can result in a NullPoitnerException. And some people who abuse Exceptions for something like this - NO NO NO, wrong. So, Optional is the way to go, just check whether it contains a value and then fetch it. And handle the situation where no value was found, if that is possible.

Comment: Thanks for your explained answer the issue is resolved now. @Benjamin Maurer. According to your suggestion i will try to learn more about optional class. I wanted to upvote your answer but cannnot due to my beginner status on this website. People dont stick to the beginners because they cant upvote. 10 people viewed my question but a single person answered. Thanks Benjamin.

Comment: Alright, no problem. you can accept it, if you like. The check mark next to the vote buttons. cheers.

Comment: I just saw your answer.. This isn't exactly how this site is supposed to work. You post your question - you may answer it yourself - but if someone else answers your question and it works, you accept that persons answer, instead of writing the same thing again as your own answer...

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was solve by

In controller

ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

```
    Optional<Employee> employee = employeeRepository.findById( employeeDto.getId());

    if (employee.isPresent()) {



        modelAndView.addObject("employeeDto", employee.get());

        System.out.println(employee);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Error Found"); // error message
    }
```

In views