# Understanding how to use JSP EL expressions to access properties of a Object

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags

I am new to J2EE development. I am unable to understand how/why this following code snippet works. The below class has the following problems:

1. The class has non-zero constructor.
2. "getname" accessor method is wrongly typed, it should be
   "getName".
3. There is no corresponding "setName" mutator method.

```
/* Java class  */

public class HelloBean {

    private String name = "Hello Bean";

    public HelloBean(String test) {
        this.name = test;
    }

    public String getname() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

// End of Java Class 
// Code in jsp page (only relevant code is shown)<br>
```

```
<%
    HelloBean test = new HelloBean("HelloWorld");
    pageContext.setAttribute("test", test);
%>

<p>The value=${test["name"]}</p
```

Output: (the below output is shown with no errors or exceptions thrown)

---

The value=HelloWorld

---

Test Environment:
Tomcat 7 (jdk 1.6)

Comment: This is most probably because the field `name` is declared **public**. Hence, it is being directly accessed bypassing the getter method `getname()` (hence ,the getter method is irrelevant even though it is wrongly typed). Try making `name` private and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even when I declared the field name to be "private", nothing changes and I still get the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the value for the `HelloBean(String test)` constructor. As your `String name` is the global variable for the class `HelloBean`. the syntax `${test["name"]}` will interpret the `name` value.

It is equivalent to the java's `ObjName.VariableName` which will print its value.You could try it as `${name}` which will throw `InvalidProperyException` on the setter and getter errors.

This [Can JSP EL do direct attribute access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121166/can-jsp-el-do-direct-attribute-access) might help